# Get config value for specific store from admin area

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, system.xml, system-config, core-config-data

I'm building a custom module for both Magento 1.9.x and 2.x. In the module's settings I want to get one of the config value i.e. I have a text field and when the user save the settings, I use the string put in this text area, saved in the database, to fill a select box and do other things in my module's settings.

My question is how can I access this value if I have a multistore? I'm able to access only the value of `default config`.

I think I need to get the scope id and use it to access the value but I don't know how to get it within the settings.

**Update 1:**

I don't know how can I get the store id from admin (in particular in configuration settings area). How can I get it?

I'll explain better my problem.
In my `system.xml` I have some fields that have a `frontend model` that I wrote (like a checkbox and a select box). In the frontend model, I need to get a value of the configuration itself. It's an api key (I can get it only after the user saves the settings). This api key can be different for each store, so in the frontend model I should get the value of the specific store, but I don't know how can I get the store id.

**Update 2 (Solution in Magento 1.9.x)**

I found the solution for Magento 1.9.x in this question:
[How to get current store id from current scope in admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6833/how-to-get-current-store-id-from-current-scope-in-admin). This is the function that returns the store_id

```
public function getStoreId()
{
   if (strlen($code = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getStore())) // store level
   {
      $store_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($code)->getId();
   }
   elseif (strlen($code = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getWebsite())) // website level
   {
      $website_id = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($code)->getId();
      $store_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id)->getDefaultStore()->getId();
   }
   else // default level
   {
      $store_id = 0;
   }
   return $store_id;
}
```

And this is the code for get the config value

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $this->getStoreId());
```

I'm searching the solution for Magento 2.x

**Update 3 (Solution in Magento 2.x)**

I solved my problem also in Magento 2.x. I use this to get the storeId:

```
$storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
```

It works only in my frontend model because it extends `\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field`.

In the helper I have the function:

```
public function getConfig($configPath, $storeId = null)
{
   return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($configPath, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
}
```

When I am in the frontend model I obtain `$storeId` and I use:

```
$this->helper->getConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $storeId);
```

When I am anywhere I use:

```
$this->helper->getConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**=> For Magento 1.9 :**

**Get Store Id :**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

**Get Config Value :**

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
```

as per store vise :

```
$storeId = 2; // ID of the store you want to fetch the value of
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $storeId);
```

**=> For Magento 2 :**

**Get Store Id :**

```
protected $storeManager;    

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    array $data = []
)
{        
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get store identifier
 *
 * @return  int
 */
public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
```

**Get Config Value :**

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    array $data = []
    ){
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
     $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    public function getMyValue(){
        $myvalue = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
         return $myvalue;
    }
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't know `$storeId`. I updated my question

Comment: I update my answer. Please check it @Vixent

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 1.9.X you will need to pass value of store id:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $store_id)
```

and for Magento 2, follow link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78473/24878

Thanks

Comment: My problem is that I don't know `$store_id`. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 you need to use following code.

Just Use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig` in your constructor argument and set the class property:

$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

Below is complete code:

```
protected $scopeConfig;
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
   \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

) 
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    parent::__construct($context,
      scopeConfig
    );
}
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: Thanks but it isn't a solution for my problem. This is solution for a single store.

Comment: How to set the scope i mean store view for selected admin user using module https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/322871/57334

Answer (score 0):

Update code config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <admin_system_config_changed_section_custommodule>
            <observers>
                <custommodulesave>
                    <class>admin_system_config_changed_section_custommodule/adminhtml_system_config_backend_admin_observer</class>
                    <method>saveConfig</method>
                </custommodulesave>
            </observers>
        </admin_system_config_changed_section_custommodule>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Add observer at Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Backend/Admin/Observer.php

```
<?php 

class Namespace_Custommodule_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Backend_Admin_Observer
{
    /**
    * Save configuration with encryption
    */
    public function saveConfig($observer)
    {
        $user = 'my custom field data';
        $password = 'my custom field data';
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getData();
        $scope = $data['store'];
        if($scope == ''){
            $scope = 'default';
        }
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($scope);
        $scopeId = $store->getId();
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode);
        Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig($userConfig, $user, $scope, $scopeId);
        Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig($passConfig, md5($password), $scope, $scopeId);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution from Magento 1, adminhtml controller ajax call to get and set value in the correct view

in phtml ajax Request add

```
parameters: {store: "<?php echo (string)Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getStore() ?>", website: "<?php echo (string)Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getWebsite() ?>"},
```

In controller add these functions

```
private function getAdminStoreConfig($params, $path)
{
    if (isset($params['store']) && $params['store']) {
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($params['store']);
        return Mage::getStoreConfig($path, $store);
    } elseif (isset($params['website']) && $params['website']) {
        $website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($params['website']);
        return $website->getConfig($path);
    } else {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig($path);
    }
}

private function saveAdminStoreConfig($params, $path, $value)
{
    if (isset($params['store']) && $params['store']) {
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($params['store']);
        Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig($path, $value, 'stores', $store->getId());
    } elseif (isset($params['website']) && $params['website']) {
        $website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($params['website']);
        Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig($path, $value, 'websites', $website->getId());
    } else {
        Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig($path, $value, 'default', Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    }
}
```

In the Action

```
$this->saveAdminStoreConfig($this->getRequest()->getParams(), $value, $val);
$this->getAdminStoreConfig($params, $path);
```